# Adding Many Saved Images in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

The application I'm trying to build will have a lot of images displayed (in ImageViews), and I'm not fetching them from a server/online service as it will need to be used offline. I know I can just dump them in the res/drawable directories, but I was wondering if there's any way to optimize this. Is there a way to somehow compress these images (besides making them smaller, they're already as small as I need) or use some other sort of android tool to better store them locally on the device?

I could just be overlooking a well used feature, and if so, it'd be great if someone could point me to that.

Edit: If I were to compress the images somehow, I would need to decompress at runtime or something, and that would take another thread/loading time. I'm not sure how to do that either, so I'm just brainstorming various ways, and I thought someone here would've come across this at some point.

Comment: ^That's true, but still a lot of pictures can add up. It's not a major problem, I was just wondering if there's another solution. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, this is a good read - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips

> **When saving image assets, remove unnecessary metadata**
>
> Although the Android SDK tools will automatically compress PNGs when
>   packaging application resources into the application binary, a good
>   practice is to remove unnecessary headers and metadata from your PNG
>   assets. Tools such as OptiPNG or Pngcrush can ensure that this
>   metadata is removed and that your image asset file sizes are
>   optimized.

Outside of all other compression logic the above would be the place to start. Also when you say "optimize" - do you mean optimize the way images/drawables are loaded in your app or just the amount of space (on disk) the app will consume?

Comment: I meant just the amount of space that it will consume. Thanks for the answer, I'll be sure to read.